# How to unit test an angular 2 component when I don't care about the dependencies? I just want to test some inner functions

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I'm new to writing unit tests, and unfortunately I've already built a few "complicated" (for me) components which I am having a hard time even beginning to write tests for.

Here's a snippet of my code, including the constructor.  Basically, I don't really care right now about these dependencies, I want to test some inner functions such as resizing based on array size, etc.  For these, I can just create an Array.fill and should be good to go.

```
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {

  photos = [];

  galleryState: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<any>,
    private photoActions: PhotoActions,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.galleryState = this.store.select<any>(state => state.photos.gallery);
  }
}
```

In my other components which have nothing in the constructor, instantiating the component in my test is as simple as `new SomeComponent()`.

However, in the `GalleryComponent` above, I am wondering if there is a way that I can literally ignore the dependencies completely (for now), and instead just instantiate the component in a way that I can test some inner functions easily.  For example, say I had the following function inside GalleryComponent:

```
function timesByTwo(number) {
  return number * 2;
}
```

This is not at all related to any of the dependencies, so how can I just test that one function given that this component has 3 dependencies?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you truly don't care about testing anything at all that is associated with your dependencies, then in your spec you can just construct your component with null values for those dependencies.

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
describe('App: Test', () => {

  let component: AppComponent;

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = new AppComponent(null, null, null);
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`Should return 4`, () => {
    expect(component.timesByTwo(2)).toEqual(4);
  });
}
```

To get around your current usage of this.store.select in your constructor you can modify your constructor like so

```
constructor(
    private store: Store<any>,
    private photoActions: PhotoActions,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    if(this.store == null){
        this.galleryState = null;
    }else{
        this.galleryState = this.store.select<any>(state => state.photos.gallery);
    }
  }
```

Otherwise you can mock your Store component in your test page. An example

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'
export class MockService extends EventService{

  constructor() { super(null); }

  getEvents(user:string){
    return Observable.of([{val: "test"}]);
  }
}
```

and then modify my code from above to be

```
let component: AppComponent;
let mockService: MockService;

      beforeEach(() => {
        mockService = new MockService()
        component = new AppComponent(null, mockService, null);
      });
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, but it gives me an error:  `cannot read property 'select' of null.`

Comment: Ah. My bad. I missed the fact that your constructor used one of your dependencies. You will either need to move that line out of the constructor or mock that dependency in your tests. You could also just surround it in an if statement for a short-term fix and check if this.store is null or not

Comment: if I was to mock the dependency so that `this.galleryState = null`, how would I do that?  Sorry if I am asking dumb questions, I am new to unit testing, and since Angular 2 released the final docs for testing, I'm trying to learn it now.  It is a lot harder than I thought.. :(

Comment: No problems. I have been going through the same stuff :D. Let me know if the edit clears things up or not. I included an example mock only because I don't know what your Store component looks like

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah I've only been programming since January and my last project we did not have unit tests.  On this project we do, and it is really time consuming.  I understand how they are valuable, for example I have written some unit tests for a couple services.  However, the component unit tests are really confusing, especially because I don't want to use the test bed, I only want to test the data in my component :(  Don't really have anyone here to teach me how to do testing, and i am finding it really hard to learn by just reading tutorials on testing a super simple component

Comment: I think I will just use the conditional for now.  I am not sure how to get the mockStore to work, since it gives me a lot more errors such as _.dispatcher is missing, etc.